# Up and Down scroll page JavaScript navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have up and down arrows on the right hand side of each section where if you click them it scrolls either up or down sections.

```
<div class="next_section"><a id="after_contact"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/img/arrow_top.png" width="73" height="36" alt="Prev Section"></a></div> 
<div class="next_section"><a id="after_work5"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/img/arrow_next.png" width="73" height="36" alt="Next Section"></a></div>
```

Problem is, not all of the arrows are working to scroll up and down the page. Some work, some don't. I have made the  on each correct to my knowledge with it being an area above or below but if you click on some arrows, it won't do anything.

Any one know what is going wrong?

URL: http://www.londonadvertising.com/2011
Pastie link: http://pastie.org/2913679

Many Thanks

Comment: so where is the javascript? Could you slice it a bit more to have a beter idea where to look for your problem?

Comment: shuold explain the problem and point us to your issue, it becomes difficult to get into your question and help you.

Comment: I think this is it. Sorry I just took over the development of this page and unsure what was used. I think this is it: http://www.londonadvertising.com/2011/wp-content/themes/london/js/jquery.nav.min.js and 
http://www.londonadvertising.com/2011/wp-content/themes/london/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the page navigation is that not all the < a > tag ids are unique.

The JavaScript is only finding the first the element with a particular ID and only that one will work. All others with the name ID after that will not do anything.

If you check, the only arrows that work are the first occurrences of a particular ID.

Ensure that all < a >  tags under a div will class 'next_section' have a unique ID

```
<div class="next_section first">
 <a id="after_work1"> <!-- <<<< ID must be unique -->
   <img src="something.jpg" alt="Next Section">
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Still having issues I'm afraid. If you have a look at http://www.londonadvertising.com/2011/ you can see my code. Not sure of what the best script to use to enable ScrollTo is either?

Comment: The javascript you were using when I looked at this originally was working fine apart from the above mentioned issue. How come you changed scripts? The original would work fine if the ID's were all unique.